# Connect a pen/thumb/flash drive through ethernet port

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, ethernet, pen

I want to connect a pendrive throuth the ethernet port on a linux OS.
Is that possible ?

I did find this on ebay, [USB-male to ETHERNET-female](http://cgi.ebay.com/USB-A-Female-to-Ethernet-RJ45-Adapter-Connector_W0QQitemZ280442417790QQcmdZViewItemQQptZLH_DefaultDomain_0?hash=item414babb27e), is this of any use?

Comment: The (now defunct) Linksys NSLU2 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NSLU2 used to do this.  I'm somewhat skeptical that the device you linked can do the same at a fraction of the size and cost.

Comment: Firstly, that thing doesn't look like it has any logic at all.  I'm going to guess what it's primarily used for is to attach a USB stick to a router or modem to reflash a firmware to it via its Console port.  Console ports are usually RJ45 connector, but not Ethernet -- Cisco units have their own RJ45-to-RS232 cable.  Some newer units might feature USB data over the RJ45 port.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The eBay auction you pointed to reminds of devices where you can extend USB connections over CAT5 wiring.  That would extend the range the USB device can be from the computer, but the device I'm thinking of is not compatible with IP networks, it merely changed the electrical wiring from a USB cable to CAT5 cable.

I agree with hyperslug that the [NSLU2](http://www.linksysbycisco.com/us/en/products/NSLU2) would work, which is still available.

I did a quick search and found [Addonics NAS Adapter](http://www.addonics.com/products/nas/nasu2.asp) which is probably closer to what you were looking for.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:** Found another [Hitachi SimpleNET NAS](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002CMEIV6), this one has two USB ports.

Comment: @dhasu, also note that the Addonics NAS adapter uses its own power source and is around USD 60.  Slick device though, a miniature NAS.